# Dynamic Chart in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, charts, wxpython

I am essentially trying to replicate the google finance chart, but for sensor data. I would like to embed the chart in a GUI and have it update on a timer (which samples the sensor for it's value). I would like to incorporate panning, resizing, and adding moving averages, much like the google finance charts, all of which is updated at some steady interval.

Much of my code base is already in python, so I would like to stick with it. Can this be done with Python?

I have checked out matplotlib, but I am not sure if it can do dynamic charts. I am using wxPython to create the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across Chaco from Enthought.

http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/

It is an open source framework written in Python that binds with wx, Qt etc and more usable than matplotlib for building full applications. Very usable and easily customizable. You can use the packaged panning, zooming tools or build your own.

I would suggest downloading the epd-free package to ensure you get all dependencies if you choose to move ahead with it.

http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php/

Answer (score 0):

I just implement a method to draw dynamic charts in ipython notebook, you can check my blog post here : http://litaotao.github.io/dynamic-charts-matplotlib-alternative-ipython-notebook-python-drawing-js

and bellow is a screenshot:

[image]